# POST request not redirecting to https

Tags: php, nginx, postman

This is my `example.conf`'s `nginx` config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.net;
  return 301 https://api.example.net$request_uri;
  access_log off;
  error_log /dev/stderr;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/example_api/public;
  server_name api.example.net;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.net/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.net/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH";
    add_header Access-control-Allow-Headers "Content-Range, Authorization,X-Requested-With, counter, id_token, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, Cache-Control, Content-Type, MyApp-Handle-Errors-Generically";
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Range, Authorization, id_token, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, Cache-Control, Content-Type, MyApp-Handle-Errors-Generically";
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age "31536000";
}

  #location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350978/nginx-serving-only-but-not-any-other-files
  location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    fastcgi_pass api:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH";
    add_header Access-control-Allow-Headers "Content-Range, Authorization,X-Requested-With, counter, id_token, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, Cache-Control, Content-Type, MyApp-Handle-Errors-Generically";
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Range, Authorization, id_token, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, Cache-Control, Content-Type, MyApp-Handle-Errors-Generically";
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age "31536000";
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }

  access_log off;
  error_log /dev/stderr;
}
```

The issue is when I send a `POST` request from `POSTMAN` in `http`, I get this error:

```
api.example.net/api/user/register/checkuser?phone=0123456789

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive" />
    <title>An Error Occurred: Method Not Allowed</title>
...
```

But if change URL to `https`, there's no issue:

```
https://api.example.net/api/user/register/checkuser?phone=0123456789

{"data":{"status":1},"meta":[]}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

I should mention that we had a migration from old server `Caddy web server` to current one `nginx`, and both are Dockerized (extra info only).

Comment: Use return 307 or 308 instead of 301, otherwise the POST is changed to a GET by the browser.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks, it's resolved now. I saw `GET` instead of `POST` in access_log and that was strange for me:) Could you please write this as answer so that I can vote you up for this favor? And if possible, provide docs or write please the reason why I should use 307/308.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7231.pdf) section 6.4.2, regarding the *301 Moved Permanently* status code:

> Note: For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
> method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this behavior
> is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code can be used
> instead.

Comment: Thanks for the RFC. I have a question: As I see https://www.drlinkcheck.com/blog/http-redirects-301-302-303-307-308, code 308 is not supported by some relative old browsers like IE11, then can I have an `if` block that `if request is POST, then use return 308`? I do not think users use IE11, but that's a question in my mind.

Comment: There are probably many features on your website that will not work with very old browsers. You need to decide how much backwards compatibility you need to support.